# Using subspace theorem to decide on real vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I use the subspace theorem to decide if the set of all real polynomials of any degree are real vector spaces?

Comment: What is the subspace theorem?

Comment: 0. Non empty
1. closed under addition
2. closed under scalar multiplication

Comment: I know the definition of a subspace. If I understand well, you want to prove the set of all polynomials is a subspace of some vector space?

Comment: @Bernard That is not the definition of subspace, that is a theorem.

Comment: The question is asking to use the subspace theorem to decide if the set of all real polynomials of any degree are vector spaces with the usual operations

Comment: @Jenny subspaces are relative entities. That is, they are subsets of vectors spaces that also happen to be vector spaces themselves. To apply the theorem mentioned, it should be established that the set of real polynomials are a subset of some vector space (perhaps the complex polynomials). Otherwise, you are doing nothing more than proving that the set of real polynomials is a vector space without respect to a larger set (you’d have to verify the 8 or so vector space axioms).

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a definition (Bourbaki, Algebra, Ch. I, *Algebraic structures*, §4, n°3). Anyway, it's unimportant –  just to explain why I wondered what was this ‘theorem’. What puzzles me is why you mention a single set of polynomials and several vector spaces?

Comment: How is the set of polynomials defined, for you?